# More than 1 controllers in Symfony for user types?

Tags: symfony

How I can use different controllers according user types, say Admin and Normal user. Currently, I have a default controller for admin. If I want to use more than one controller what should I have to do, I mean the files I need to change.

1. Admin : DefaultController.php
2. Normal : NormalController.php

Answer (score 0):

Why not use different endpoints instead of controllers?
Then you can set it in `security.yml` and in the route definitions.
Check this out: http://symfony.com/doc/current/security.html